# How to convert Mysql database to Postgresql in Linux?

Tags: linux, mysql, database, postgresql, conversion

I have a large Mysql database containing tens of tables which I need to convert to Postgresql. I have tried a couple of ancient Perl scripts which  I found here and there but none of them did the job correctly. So wondering if there is any free and efficient tool/script which you have tried and actually does the conversion with the least hassle.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Did you try

```
mysqldump --compatible=postgresql yourdatabase >dump.sql
```